# BERT transfer learning for long text: output predictions from multiple chunks

Tags: python, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, huggingface-tokenizers

This is for a kaggle [project](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/nbme-score-clinical-patient-notes) on labeling clinical patient notes: for a given example (pn_history), we need to identify the text (start, end) that correspond to specific list of entities (feature_text). I am planning to use the clinicalBERT on [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT), which was trained using max sequence length of 128, so I added the sliding window parameters during tokenization:

```
out = tokenizer(
        data["feature_text"],
        data["pn_history"],
        truncation=config['truncation'],
        max_length=config['max_length'],
        padding=config['padding'],
        return_offsets_mapping=config['return_offsets_mapping'],
        #process long seq with a sliding window
        stride=config['stride'],
        return_overflowing_tokens=config['return_overflowing_tokens'],
)
```

The sliding window is working because each example generates N overlapping chunks with sequence length=128. The model architecture is basically BERT followed by two fully connected layers. I can see the shape of predicted output (ie. probability of the text corresponds to the feature_text) for each original example is N * 128. With any output greater than the threshold (eg. 0.5), I can then get a (start, end) pair.

Now because of the N overlapping chunks, the predicted output is likely different between different chunks for the same (start, end) pair, how should I combine the the outputs from the N chunks?